# jQuery sticky nav scrolltop

Tags: jquery, if-statement, fixed, sticky

I use a simple script to 'sticky' my sidebar when you scroll down past the header and 'unsticky' it when you scroll up past the header. It simply adds or removes the class 'fixed' - works perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var stickyNavTop = $('#content').offset().top; 

  var stickyNav = function(){  
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

  if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
    $('#left').addClass('fixed');  
  } else {  
    $('#left').removeClass('fixed');   
  } 

  stickyNav();  

  $(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyNav();  
  });  
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/6vE9e/**

However, the sidebar now runs over the footer. Also, when the sidebar is longer than you resolution is high, you can never see the full content.

So I was thinking:

```
var sidebarHeight = $('#left').height(); 
var footerPos = $('footer').offset().top;  
var stopSticky = footerPos - sidebarHeight;

if (scrollTop > stopSticky){
  $('#left').css('position','absolute').css('top', stopSticky);
}
```

But this is where I get stuck and I don't know how to work this into the script. Any tips?

Any general comments about the script are very welcome too, I'm learning every day :-)